# How can I switch to Rich Edit 4.1 (or higher) in Delphi 11.1.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, richedit

I have character encoding problems with the base `TRichEdit` component in Delphi 11.1.5. It does not handle in its output RTF the situation if I switch the keyboard language and type hun/en special characters (`ő`/`ű`/`²`). It just stores one codepage at the `\ansicpgN` and does not store it in the font table item `\fN\cpgN`, and it uses `\'NN` codes instead of `\uNNNN`.
Bing said if I switch to RichEdit 4.1, it will solve my problem. But how can I switch? Could somebody help me?

Bing said I should call this in the `OnCreate` event of the form containing the `TRichEdit` control:

```pascal
SetWindowLong( RichEdit1.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, HashCode( 'RICHEDIT41' ) );
```

But it could not define the proper hash function to provide a working hash code.

Here it is a very simple, but problematic RTF doc:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1250\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1038{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset238 Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset238 Times New Roman;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.19041}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs24\'f5\f1\lang1033\'b2\cf1\f2\lang1038\'fb\f0\par
}
```

In this example, I should convert the ANSI `\'F5` and `\'fb` characters with codepage 1250, but the ANSI `\'b2` character with codepage 1252 to get the right UTF-16 string : `'ő²ű'`.

The `\fN` selects the font, but these store the `\fcharsetN` and not the required `\cpgX` values.

But with RichEdit 4.1 the `\cpgN` I won't miss at all, because it stores the special character codes encoded in UTF-16 format : `\uNNNN` in the contents section.

Answer (score 2):

`TRichEdit` already uses RichEdit 4.1, and has since the initial release of Delphi 11:

[TRichEdit Component updated to RichEdit 4.1 (MSFTEDIT.dll)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/What%27s_New#TRichEdit_Component_updated_to_RichEdit_4.1_.28MSFTEDIT.dll.29)

In any case, `TRichEdit` itself does not (and never has) format the actual RTF itself, that is all Microsoft's doing.  So whatever problems you are having with the RTF should be taken up with Microsoft, not Embarcadero.  `TRichEdit` simply sends the underlying RichEdit an [`EM_STREAMOUT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamout) message and Microsoft does all the work to create the RTF, `TRichEdit` just writes the output to the caller's provided `TStream` object.

Also, you can't pass in a *hash code* to `SetWindowLong(GWL_WNDPROC)`, as it wants an actual function pointer instead.  Bing is giving you bad/incomplete information.

Comment: If D11.1.5 uses RichEdit 4.1 what should I do to get the spec chars in UTF16 format?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper as I said, you will have to ask Microsoft about that, see what they require to get the output you want. On the other hand, your RTF example says `generator Riched20 10.0.19041`, which seems wrong, so you should ask Embarcadero about that to make sure there is not simply a bug causing `TRichEdit` to use the wrong RichEdit version. You can debug the VCL source code for yourself to verify that, simply turn on `Use debug dcus` in your Project settings.